dplyr::mutate()におけるif_else()で, "size" に関するエラー
csvデータを読み込んで，mutate()とif_else()を使って新しい列を追加しようとしています．
csvデータは20行あります．
ex.csv
name value
hoge 5
huga 7
piyo 4
puka 2
...

以下コード
library('tidyverse')
d <- read.csv('ex.csv', sep = '\t', header = T)
d2 <- d %>% 
    mutate(num = if_else(row_number() == 1, 
                         value, 
                         if_else(d2[row_number() - 1, 1] == 'hoge', 
                                 d2[row_number() - 1, 2] + value, 
                                 value)))

エラー
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `num = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `true` must have size 19, not size 20.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `num = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `true` must have size 19, not size 20.
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─d_test %>% ...
  2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
  5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
  7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
  8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
  9. ├─dplyr::if_else(...)
 10. └─dplyr::if_else(...)

エラーメッセージの true` must have size 19, not size 20. がどのように解決できるのかわからず困っています．
お力をお貸しいただけますと幸いです．

この件について続きの質問があります．もし差し支えなければこちらのご検討もお願いできますと幸いです．https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/99711/mutate%e3%81%a7%e8%bf%bd%e5%8a%a0%e4%b8%ad%e3%81%ae%e5%80%a4%e3%82%92%e5%8f%82%e7%85%a7%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95

dplyr::lag() を使います。
ex.csv
name    value
hoge    5
huga    7
piyo    4
puka    2
hoge    10
huga    15
piyo    20
puka    30

Script
d2 <- d %>%
    mutate(num = if_else(row_number() > 1 & lag(name) == 'hoge',
                         lag(value) + value,
                         value))

d2

#   name value num
# 1 hoge     5   5
# 2 huga     7  12
# 3 piyo     4   4
# 4 puka     2   2
# 5 hoge    10  10
# 6 huga    15  25
# 7 piyo    20  20
# 8 puka    30  30


ありがとうございます！重要な問題が解決しました！lag()に相当する関数のことが調べてもわかりませんでしたので，非常に助かりました．
