mutate()で追加中の値を参照する方法
csvデータを読み込んで，mutate()とif_else()を使って新しい列を追加しようとしています．
一つ前の行の値を参照してmutete()を行う方法を，こちらでお教えいただきました．
こちらの続きなのですが，mutate()で追加中の値を参照する方法はあるのでしょうか．
csvデータは20行あります．
ex.csv
name value
hoge 5
huga 7
piyo 4
puka 2
...

コード
library('tidyverse')
d <- read.csv('ex.csv', sep = '\t', header = T)
d2 <- d %>%
    mutate(num = if_else(row_number() > 1 & lag(name) == 'hoge',
                         lag(num) + value,
                         value))

エラー
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `num = if_else(...)`.
Caused by error:
! object 'num' not found
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─d_test %>% ...
  2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
  3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
  5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
  7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
  8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
  9. ├─dplyr::if_else(...)
 10. └─dplyr::lag(len2)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 3 hidden frames.

類似の質問の繰り返しになり恐縮です．
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします．
